# Is there a countdown timer in Android?

Tags: clock

I searched for a countdown timer, and I was not able to find it. It should be there in every phone... Is it coming with the standard Clock app?

Comment: The Droid X comes with blur which come with an alarm clock and timer.

Comment: Depends on the manufacturer of the device. But most devices (Android 3.0 and up) have a countdown timer in the clock application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until Android 4.2 there is no stock Countdown timer, with Android 4.2 [there will be one](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1970309).

Some alternative Interfaces like Touchwiz (Samsung Devices) have added a Countdown Timer for a long time, but stock Android (AOSP) had this first in 4.2.

Comment: I had one in 4.1 though?

Comment: see edit :) 4char

Comment: But I was using Cyanogen ;)

Comment: cyanogen is just aosp based and they introduced it before also

Answer (score 3):

There is not a countdown app built in to android, but there are a ton to choose from on the [android market](https://market.android.com/search?q=countdown%20timer&c=apps).

Answer (score 1):

There's definitely a built-in stopwatch for Android (HTC) 4. With my old Android 2.3, I used "[Stopwatch & Countdown Timer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.be.android.stopwatch)". It seems complex, but it works well.

Answer (score 0):

I have downloaded the free [Kitchentimer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.leinardi.kitchentimer&hl=en) from googleplay that is available for android 2.1 and up. It has 3 independant timers that can give an alert sound and/or vibrate after the timer has finished.

Answer (score 0):

I have the HTC Amaze, my Android version is 4.0.3. It has a timer built into the clock screen tabs. So it may be dependent on your phone itself, not just the Android version.

Answer (score 0):

There's a timer included in the standard clock since Android 4.2. However, you can't store your timers with that one.